# Ansible playbook, adhoc var not able to use between two host

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Unable to set and use hostvars, declared a var in host1, that I want to use in localhost. I've followed many suggestions and none work for me to resolve error
`The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['host1']" is undefined`

Steps are

- host1 copies a file to local via `fetch`, using `register`
- then using `set_fact` store the destination path as includes host ("dest": "/var/log/ansible_runs/10.xxx.xxx.251/tmp/xxx_env_pin.tmp",). This works under host1
- next localhost uses var "file_n_path" created from host1 (When working will use path to append to another file).

```
# Run script on remote machine
---
- hosts: host1
 remote_user: one
 tasks:
   - name: Store file into local
     fetch:
       src: /tmp/xxx_env_one.tmp
       dest: /var/log/ansible_runs
     register: fetch_output1
   - set_fact: file_n_path="{{fetch_output1.dest}}"

   - debug: 
       var: fetch_output1

   - debug:
       msg: " 1a. {{ file_n_path }}"


#   --/ Run on local machine to append copied file
- hosts: localhost
 connection: local
 vars:
   m_var_frm_pin: "{{ hostvars['host1']['file_n_path'] }}"
 tasks:
   - debug: 
       msg: " 2a. {{ m_var_frm_pin }}"
```

Output

```
PLAY [host1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts gather_subset=['all'], gather_timeout=10] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251]

TASK [Store file intolocal dest=/var/log/ansible_runs, src=/tmp/xxx_env_pin.tmp] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251]

TASK [set_fact file_n_path={{fetch_output1.dest}}] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251]

TASK [debug var=fetch_output1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251] => {
    "fetch_output1": {
        "changed": false,
        "checksum": "dc828a5f0c48456c72e5849891736135f89b265c",
        "dest": "/var/log/ansible_runs/10.xxx.xxx.251/tmp/xxx_env_pin.tmp",
        "failed": false,
        "file": "/tmp/xxx_env_pin.tmp",
        "md5sum": "30a6d5ba55ed78832a978c53298a054c"
    }
}

TASK [debug msg= 1a. {{ file_n_path }}] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251] => {}

MSG:

 1a. /var/log/ansible_runs/10.xxx.xxx.251/tmp/xxx_env_pin.tmp


PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts gather_subset=['all'], gather_timeout=10] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug msg= 2a. {{ m_var_frm_pin }}] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['host1']" is undefined

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/Playbook_033a.yml': line 26, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - debug:
      ^ here



PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.xxx.xxx.251             : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Please do not edit answers to add information, rather post a comment or edit your question. To answer your wrong edit: it wasn't working because I badly typo'ed there. I wrote `hostsvars` (adding a plural at host) when I meant  `hostvars` , indeed. Edited my answer, this should work for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your recap, and in particular those lines `ok: [10.xxx.xxx.251]`, your problem seems to be that `host1` is not a host but a group of hosts.

If you want to access the `hostvars` of a single host in a group via its group name, you can use `hostvars[groups['group_name'][0]]['var_name']`.

So your local part of the play should be:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    m_var_frm_pin: "{{ hostvars[groups['host1'][0]]['file_n_path'] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: " 2a. {{ m_var_frm_pin }}"
```